# Scrapping google with scrapfly

Tags: python, web-scraping

Trying to scrap google with scrapfy, following https://scrapfly.io/blog/how-to-scrape-google/, I tried running

```
from collections import defaultdict
from urllib.parse import quote
from parsel import Selector
from scrapfly import ScrapeConfig, ScrapflyClient

scrapfly = ScrapflyClient("YOUR SCRAPFLY KEY")


def parse_search_results(selector: Selector):
    """parse search results from google search page"""
    results = []
    for box in selector.xpath("//h1[contains(text(),'Search Results')]/following-sibling::div[1]/div"):
        title = box.xpath(".//h3/text()").get()
        url = box.xpath(".//h3/../@href").get()
        text = "".join(box.xpath(".//div[@data-content-feature=1]//text()").getall())
        if not title or not url:
            continue
        url = url.split("://")[1].replace("www.", "")
        results.append((title, url, text))
    return results


def scrape_search(query: str, page=1, country="US"):
    """scrape search results for a given keyword"""
    # retrieve the SERP
    url = f"https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q={quote(query)}" + (f"&start={10*(page-1)}" if page > 1 else "")
    print(f"scraping {query=} {page=}")
    results = defaultdict(list)
    result = scrapfly.scrape(ScrapeConfig(url, country=country, asp=True))
    # parse SERP for search result data
    results["search"].extend(parse_search_results(result.selector()))
    return dict(results)

# Example use: scrape 3 pages: 1,2,3
for page in [1, 2, 3]:
    results = scrape_search("scrapfly blog", page=page)
    for result in results["search"]:
        print(result)
```

Without any change, but it does not work. I had:

```
results["search"].extend(parse_search_results(result.selector()))
```

> TypeError: 'Selector' object is not callable

So I tried to remove `.selector()` altogether, to see if I could see something printed. but then I had:

> AttributeError: 'ScrapeApiResponse' object has no attribute 'xpath'

Any hints from someone who used scrapfly successfully ?

Comment: I'm not running all that but from your error, I would guess that you want to use `.selector`, not `.selector()`. It says right there that `selector` is not callable, and you're trying to use `selector`'s xpath property. You need `.selector` there

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was sure that I already tried, but actually it worked.